# I need help at a simple while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

So i'm learning PHP and i need to make a while loop for an excercise.
The while loop takes a integer stored in a value and it needs to count up every single number between zero and that integer. like this :

```
$int = 8;
$i = 0
while ($i <= $int){
   //count up all the numbers in between;
}
```

and it should output something like this :

```
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8=36
```

Problem is i can't seem to figure out a way to accomplish this.

Comment: You can implement this without using any loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you use a `for` instead of a `while`, but if it's an exercise requirement than you can write:

```
$int = 8;
$i = 1;
$sum = 0;
while ($i <= $int) {
    $sum += $i;
    $i++;
}
```

A more advanced notation would be: `$sum += $i++;` (so you can remove the final `$i++`).
And a better algorithm would be: `$sum = ($int * ($int + 1)) / 2;`, this wouldn't require any loop.

Comment: No problem... consider to flag this answer as useful, please

Answer (score 0):

You can store the values in a third variable named `$sum` like so:

```
$int = 8;
$i = 0;
$sum = 0;

while ($i <= $int){
    $sum+=$i;
    $i++;
}
echo $sum;
```